# Method to find DNS hijack?

Tags: dns, malware-detection

I'm getting worried. For one specific computer where I run win10 and chrome i maybe once every 30-60 days get a different web page compared to the url I manually type in.

I have tested kaspersky and avast, but none of them found anything on my computer.

I suspect that some service on my computer injects itself every now and then between chrome and the DNS server to give me the wrong ip address for the site that I'm looking for.

I have a ubiquity edge router and can not see any odd setting in it.

I have tried to run wireshark, but since it happens so rarely I have not managed to have wireshare running while this happens.

The pages that I get to instead of where I want to get is online gambling sites.

I have searched the web after instructions on how to trouble shoot this and tried many without any success.

What is the best working instruction to sort this out? Grateful for any help or direction.

Comment: An extension in browser may be more the cause. Otherwise, do you get the same problem from another computer in same network? Do you have problems on HTTPS websites? Also your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: I have disabled some extensions, but I will disable all extensions now. No I have not found any problems on the other computers on this network.